# AWK|BASH, use double FS and ternary operator

Tags: bash, awk

Is it possible?

I was wondering how to do:

1. Count fields differentiated by comma.
2. Only the obtained first field of the previous step, count words differentiated by space.
3. If there is more than 2 words, print `NF`, otherwise `$0`.

**Input**

```
cellular biol immunogenet, rosario
escuela estadist, medellin
medellin
```

**Expected output**

```
rosario
escuela estadist, medellin
medellin
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this awk command

```
awk -F, '{if (split($1, a, " ") > 2) print $NF; else print}' file
```

This will output

```
 rosario
escuela estadist, medellin
medellin
```

If you want to get rid of the space before `$NF`, use this awk command

```
awk -F, '{if (split($1, a, " ") > 2) print substr($NF, 2); else print}' file
```

This will output

```
rosario
escuela estadist, medellin
medellin
```

**Explanation**

We use the `-F,` to set the field separator to a comma.

For every line, we split the first field into the array `a`, using a single space as the separator. We check if the return value is greater than 2 (the split function returns the number of elements), and then we print the `substr($NF, 2)`, which removes the space at the beginning of `$NF`. Otherwise, we just print the whole line using `print`.

Comment: Thank you, would you explain it? please : )

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F, 'split($1,a,/ /) > 2 {$0=$NF} 1' input.txt
```

`split($1,a,/ /)` splits `$1` on the regex `/ /` and stores them into the array `a`. It returns the resulting length of the array.

So if `$1` is split into more than two words, then change the line `$0` to `$NF`.

The lone `1` is a shorthand that makes sure it prints each line.

Comment: Thank you, would you explain it? please : )